# Sometimes I wonder how it will end

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

Complete the verse with a body part,

> Eco nut our da,
>   We fight on ye dead,
>   Entry _____

and the sequence with a letter,

> d, e, r, y, k, t, h, r, e, y, _

Comment: Are the two parts related? Or are we supposed to figure that out for ourselves?

Comment: Yep - the two parts are related.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to the first part is

> ILEUM - part of the word millennium

and the second part is

> m. The last letter of the word millennium

because the clues represent

> time, in increasing length

I figured this out just by

> putting the letters next to the words and after I noticed `day` and `week`, the rest fell into place
>     `eco - d     second`
>     `nut - e     minute`
>     `our - r     hour`
>     `da - y      day`
>     `we - k      week`
>     `fight - t   fortnight`
>     `on - h      month`
>     `ye - r      year`
>     `dead - e    decade`
>     `entry - y   century`

I couldn't figure out

> why the other letters are missing, but it turns out this wasn't part of the puzzle.

Comment: You've really got it (the missing letters aren't part of the answer)! Maybe could find a gutsy word for the first part (and the title is an overall hint).

Comment: Rot13 VYRHZ. I'd feel cheap to post a separate answer after your work.

Comment: Also M Oehm is right with his hip alternative answer - also a five letter, three syllable body, part :D